# Update a column value with another column value by default

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

I have a table like

```
+ Column1 | Column2 | Column3 +
+---------|---------|---------+
+   1     | val.txt | val.txt +
+   2     | test.xls| test.xls+
+   3     | abc.dwg | abc.dwg +
+   4     | y.txt   | y.txt   +
+   5     | kylk.txt|         + 
...............................
+---------|---------|---------+
```

Now when there is an empty value in column 3 then by default it should add the value of column 2, can that be done within the same table column with default condition?

Thought of creating a function and trigger and
I have tried by creating a function but failed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_gen()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$BEGIN
update public.tab_name
set column3=column2
where column3 is null;
END$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Is there a way to give a default condition on table column itself or how to solve it function and trigger
Am using postgres 9.4 in centos 7.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `UPDATE` in a trigger is dangerous. Use [the `NEW`/`OLD` special variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) instead. -- But consider not changing your table at all: it is very easy to **query** your table in the desired format: `SELECT column1, column2, coalesce(column3, column2) FROM table1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change a column value during an update or insert do **not** use `UPDATE` in the trigger, change the `NEW` record that is passed to the trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_gen()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  if new.column3 is null then
     new.column3 := new.column2;
  end if;
  return new;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

In order to make this work you need a `before` trigger:

```
create trigger tab_name_trigger
  BEFORE update or insert on tab_name
  for each row
  execute procedure fun_gen();
```

---

Creating a view that simply does this during retrieval would be **much** more efficient.

```
create view tab_name_no_null
as 
select column1, 
       column2, 
       coalesce(column3, column2) as column3
from tab_name;
```

The evaluation of `coalesce()` is cheap. The only situation where the trigger would be needed if you are searching on that column a lot and want to create an index on it.

Comment: Below is the error that getting white importing a csv file---
ERROR:  record "new" is not assigned yet
DETAIL:  The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function fun_gen() line 3 at IF

Comment: @stacky: sorry, forgot to add the `for each row` option. This only works with a row level trigger

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, its working fine, but as I import every csv file, its skipping the 1st record, was it due to this function and trigger or out of this pretext?

Comment: @stacky: that must be something with the way you import your data.